# WM_PAINT, но для Static внутри диалогового окна

Tags: winapi

Диалоговое окно создано с помощью **DialogBoxParam**, в нём имеется **Static**-контрол, на котором происходит рисование. Вернее, рисование происходит на совместимом DC, но потом нужно туда копировать.
Как я делаю?

Ловлю **WM_PAINT** в **DialogProc** и в нём делаю **BeginPaint** (указывая хендл Static-контрола), **BilBlt** (переношу из совместимого DC в DC контрола) и **EndPaint**.
Но сдаётся мне, что для отрисовки именно **Static**-контрола, а не всего диалогового окна нужно ловить что-то другое.

***Подскажите, плиз, как правильно?***

p.s. Вообще, проблема возникла после того, как я решил показать **MessageBox** из **WM_COMMAND**/**BN_CLICKED**. При наличии указанного выше обработчика **WM_PAINT** этот **MessageBox** не появляется. Вернее, оно появляется только при переключении окна на другое. Это явный глюк.
Если я указываю в **BeginPaint**/**EndPaint** хендл диалога, то как нетрудно догадаться, я начинаю рисовать на всём окно. Но тогда **MessageBox** отображается нормально...

Comment: Нашёл вариант решения: установить опцию стиля контрола **SS_OWNERDRAW** и ловить сообщение **WM_DRAWITEM** (wParam = ID контрола). Отрисовка работает (и **MessageBox** тоже), но только без **BeginPaint/EndPaint**. Сдаётся мне, что это не совсем правильно: каждый раз перерисовывать всё полностью на экране. К тому же, **WM_DRAWITEM** передаёт в lParam структуру **DRAWITEMSTRUCT** – для чего она?