# Рисование на DC (GDI)

Tags: winapi

Раньше не занимался рисованием через WinAPI на DC, сейчас изучаю этот процесс.
Хочу спросить, как правильно работать с объектами и рисовать на контролах?

Я думаю так: получаю размер клиентской части окна (контрола), на котором рисую (GetClientRect) создаю совместимый DC (CreateCompatibleDC), создаю совместимый Bitmap размером с клиентскую часть окна (CreateCompatibleBitmap), выбираю его в этом совместимом DC (SelectObject), чтобы DC имел нужный размер и цветность.

Далее вывод делаю в созданный совместимый DC, а в обработчике WM_PAINT делаю BeginPaint + BitBlt (перенос из совместимого DC в DC окна) + EndPaint.
DeleteDC этого совместимого DC для рисования и DeleteObject созданного вначале Bitmap'а делаю при закрытии окна (именно в этом порядке: сначала DeleteDC(CompatibleDC), затем DeleteObject(Bitmap)).

**Правилен ли этот процесс? Не нужно ли делать что-то ещё или можно ли пойти другим путём?**
Могу ли я удалить совместимый Bitmap (выбранный в DC) раньше, чем DC без ущерба для последнего?

---

И второй вопрос: создание карандашей, кистей и пр.

1. CreatePen (CreateSolidBrush и пр)
2. SelectObject
3. Рисую
4. DeleteObject(Pen/Brush/etc)

Если CreatePatternBrush, то:

1. LoadBitmap
2. CreatePatternBrush
3. SelectObject
4. Рисую
5. DeleteObject(Brush)
6. DeleteObject(Bitmap)

**Всё верно или где-то есть ошибка?**
Можно ли удалять карандаши/кисти до начала рисования (сразу после SelectObject)?

В MSDN написано: *Do not delete a drawing object (pen or brush) while it is still selected into a DC.*
Как же из тогда удалять? Как отменить их выбор? Относится ли это к Bitmap'ам (а не только к Pen/Brush)...

Comment: Можно рисовать без буферизации сразу на контроле

Comment: Это понятно, только при сдвиге контрола, его изображение будет потёрто. Для этого я буферизацию и делаю...

Comment: `SelectObject` возвращает предыдущий объект - сохраните его и перед удалением своего Brush/Pen/Bitmap поставьте его обратно с помощью `SelectObject`. Это будет наиболее "чисто" и в соответствии с примерами.

Comment: @Lyth, т.е. X=CreatePen, Z=SelectObject(X), Рисую, SelectObject(Z), DeleteObject(X), так?

Comment: Потерто, вызовится новый WM_PAINT и нарисуется заново. Конечно, все зависит от сложности отрисовки

Comment: Да, именно так. Это относится и к кистям, и к битмапам.

Comment: @Anton-Shchyrov, да можно, но это не всегда удобно, особенно когда рисунок создаётся постепенно или когда он сложен (например, график сложной функции – перерисовка будет менее трудоёмкой).

Comment: @Lyth, спасибо!

Comment: @Lyth, а процесс создания дополнительного DC я правильно описал?

Comment: Насколько я помню, да, всё правильно.

Comment: Главное, в **CreateCompatibleBitmap** указать hdc контрола, а не возвращённый **CreateCompatibleDC**, иначе получим моно-изображение (это для тех, кто интересуется темой и читает эти сообщения) :)

Answer (score 2):

В целом всё верно, однако `SelectObject` [возвращает](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162957(v=vs.85).aspx) предыдущий выбранный объект (для каждого типа: Bitmap, Brush, Font, Pen, Region) - сохраняйте их и выбирайте обратно перед удалением своего объекта:

```
HGDIOBJ original = NULL;
originalPen = SelectObject(hdc, myPen);
...
SelectObject(hdc, originalPen);
DeleteObject(myPen);
```

Некоторые виды объектов удалять необязательно - это те, которые можно получить функцией [GetStockObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144925(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: А если объект нужен на протяжении всей жизни DC? К примеру, создаём: CreateCompatibleDC + CreateCompatibleBitmap + SelectObject. Для удаления же достаточно будет сделать DeleteObject + DeleteDC (ну или наоборот)? Не возвращая старый Bitmap? Всё равно же DC удаляется...

Comment: А если удалить этот Bitmap сразу после SelectObject? Код таким образом работает. Тем не менее, можно ли так делать? С Pen так не прокатывает, устанавливается сразу чёрный сплошной тонкий карандаш, а вот Bitmap нормально работает...

Comment: И нужно ли восстанавливать прежний Pen, Brush и пр., если я выбрал нудный мне его через GetStockObject? Или можно выбрать и всё... я же его не удаляю?

Comment: @JinX документация просит только не удалять выбранный объект; так что если вы удаляете DC до битмапа и потом не обращаетесь ни к DC, ни к битмапу, то вроде ничего и не произойдёт. Полагаю, что вообще DC, созданные через `CreateCompatibleDC` более лояльны к наличию объектов и порядку удаления, чем прямые, полученные через `GetDC` или `BeginPaint`.

Comment: @JinX со стоковыми да, можно просто выбрать и не удалять (и сохранять прежний тоже не нужно, но это просто удобно в общем случае). Для стоковых Pen и Brush есть даже свои функции по установке цвета - `SetDCPenColor`, `SetDCBrushColor`.

Comment: Спасибо! Прошу ещё обратить внимание на смежную тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758311 . А то там что-то молчат пока все...

Comment: Кстати, Ваш код можно упросить, обойдясь без переменной myPen: `originalPen = SelectObject(hdc, GreatePen(PS_DASH, 3, 0x80)); ... ; DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc, originalPen));` :)))